# JQuery Ajax not return the alert after sent the email in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to show the alert if email sent or not

using JQuery Ajax,

this the Contact method when I am using the id of the project in it

and tried to send data using json

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(int id, String FromName, String FromEmail, String Message, String subject)
    {
        //To select email of student in current project
        var studentEmail = (from ss in db.Users
                            where ss.projectGroup == id
                            select ss.userEmail).ToArray();
        var isSuccess = false;
        var message = "";
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {

            for (int h = 0; h < studentEmail.Length; h++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                    var msg = new MailMessage();

                    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(studentEmail[h])); //replace with valid value

                    msg.Subject = subject;
                    msg.Body = string.Format(body, FromName, FromEmail, Message);
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    smtp.Send(msg);
                    isSuccess = true;
                    message = "The data has been processed!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message = "Something failed";
                }
            }
        }
        var jsonData = new { isSuccess, message };

        return Json(jsonData);
       }
```

In the view I am using script to show alert and Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formSuccess(data) {
    if (data.isSuccess) {
        alert("your email has been successfully sent to all students in this project " + data.message);
    } else {
        alert("Sending failed " + data.message);
    }
}
```

Here where I am sending the project id (pID) and send the email

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "AreaOfInterest", new { id = pID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "formSuccess" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        <strong> Contact with students </strong>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="FromName" placeholder="your name..." class="contact-name form-control" id="contact-name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="FromEmail" placeholder="your email..." class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." class="contact-subject form-control" id="contact-subject" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..." class="contact-message form-control" id="contact-message" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" />

                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .panel -->
    }
```

but after sent the email not show alert

it shows the current state

> {"isSuccess":true,"message":"The data has been processed!"}

Where is my mistake?

Comment: That means it is doing a normal form submit instead of the ajax form submit. Make sure you have the needed js files which converts your form to an ajaxy form.

Comment: Thank you for more explanation in your replay, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the JSON Response in browser because your current code is doing a normal form post instead of an ajax post.

The `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method renders a `form` tag with some additional data attributes like this

```
data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="formSuccess"
```

*If you a view source of the page, you can see this*

Now to make this form to do an ajax form submit instead of normal form submit, you need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` library in your page. This libarary is a tiny js library which basically wires up code to execute on the `submit` event on the form (with data-ajax=true attributes), prevent the normal form submit behavior and do an ajax form submit instead. If you do not include this library, your form will not do an ajax form submit, but do a normal form submit, which is what is happening to you.

The solution is to include this library

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        function formSuccess(data)
        {
            if (data.isSuccess)
            {
                alert("your email has been successfully " + data.message);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Sending failed " + data.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Assuming jQuery library is already loaded (in the layout, before executing the code from the Scripts section.

You can download this js library from nuget here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I used jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js library and downloaded it to my project using Package Manager Console but unfortunately still does not work, the alert did not show

Comment: Open the devtools and check the console tab for any script errors.

Comment: I tried many times but after I rebuild the project then its work, thank very much =)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition method in controller is : `Task<ActionResult>` while you return Json result. Try change to `Task<JsonResult>`.

P.s I don't see any Ajax in your code

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but there is no difference, same result